# inside Javascript Html checkbox not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am placing a checkbox on a table row using Javascript, but the checkbox is not working when I check it.

==> view.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   var html ="";
   html += "<tr id=" +id+ ">";
   html += "<td>" +'<input type= "checkbox" name="update[]" 
         value= "<?=" +id+ "?>"/>' + "</td>" ;
    });

 $('input[name="update[]"]').click(function(){
   alert("h2");
 });
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you have `id` declared in your code. Have you missed declaring it?

Comment: @Snel23 i want declare value but it contain row id so here id is table Row id

Comment: var html ="";
                       id = result[a].id
                    html += "<tr id=" +id+ ">";
                    html += "<td>" +'<input type= "checkbox" name="update[]" value= "<?=" +id+ "?>"/>' + "</td>" ;

Comment: @Snel23 check my code in my comment

Comment: Do you really have that jQuery operating outside of a `<script>` tag in your code, or just in this example?

Comment: @tshimkus check my code, its by mistake

Comment: Looks like a case of event delegation; those elements are dynamically generated.

Comment: @ObsidianAge yes it is dynamically generated on each table row.

Comment: You are trying to add the `click` event before the elements are being inserted. Try to place it after you insert the elements (within `$(document).ready`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide the whole code. Right the code is not provided completely.
There are many parameter missing.

Meanwhile You can also try to use on click method

```
$('input[name="update[]"]').on("click", function(){
  alert("h2");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input is added by JS. It means that this element wasn't in the DOM initially. You should try the following code:

```
 $(document).on('click', 'input[name="update[]"]', function(){
    alert("h2");
 });
```